# Глобальная обработка ошибок

Tags: python, selenium

Камрады, можно ли как-то обработать непредвиденные ошибки каким-либо общим способом? Конкретика: есть бот на селениуме, который ходит по определенному перечню форумов и отправляет сообщения в определенные темы на форуме, предварительно проделав стопицот проверок на предмет можно ли отправлять это сообщение или нет. На всякий случай: это не спам, все в рамках закона и маленького мира этих самых форумов :)
Суть вопроса в чем: бот может упасть на какой угодно строке — из-за нехорошего поведения интернета, из-за криворукости дизайнеров этих самых форумов (непредвиденные всплывающие окна, что-то еще), etc. В связи с этим вопрос: на каждую строку кидать except или все же можно как-то прописать, что если скрипт упал и я не смогла заранее предвидеть это падение, то, скажем, в этом случае зафиксировать ошибку и, например, отправить сообщение в тг с текстом "что-то пошло не так, мой генерал, вот текст ошибки: [текст ошибки]".

Comment: В идеале оба варианта. Скрипт обёрнут в глобальные try: except:, которые ловят всё необнаруженное и логируют это / сообщают в тг. Но это по идее именно на непредвиденный случай. В идеале обрабатывать частные исключения, чтобы скрипт с ними справлялся и двигал дальше. Или игнорил конкретный форум и шел на следующий, в конце сообщая с какими форумами не справился и по какой ошибке. Так будет понятней где именно возникла ошибка и легче будет с ней что-то сделать.

Comment: @Alpensin внезапно пронзила, что в except не обязательно прописывать конкретную ошибку. В целом вроде бы получилось примерно то, что хотелось, но еще наблюдаю. Спасибо :)